# OSX Custom extension icon Association

Tags: java, macos, filehandle, info.plist

I'm trying to get my application to display an icon for a custom file extension using the following code:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
           <string>My Custom Extension</string>
           <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
           <string>Viewer</string>
           <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
           <array>
                   <string>com.myapp.myext</string>
           </array>
           <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
           <string>Owner</string>
           <key>NSExportableTypes</key>
           <array>
                   <string>com.myapp.myext</string>
           </array>
       </dict>
    </array>
   <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
   <array>
           <dict>
                   <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
                   <string>Myicon.icns</string>
                   <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
                   <string>My Custom Extension</string>
                   <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
                   <array>
                           <string>public.data</string>
                   </array>
                   <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
                   <string>com.myapp.myext</string>
                   <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
                   <string>http://www.myapp.com</string>
                   <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
                   <dict>
                           <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                           <array>
                                   <string>myext</string>
                           </array>
                   </dict>
           </dict>
   </array>
```

I've tried using both *UTTypeIconFile* AND *CFBundleTypeIconFile*, and the icon is present under my Content/Resources folder inside the app bundle, but I still see a blank icon when looking at files that have my file extension

I'm not sure if it matters, but this application is launched using the **JavaApplicationStub** (it's a java app)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It's possible that Apple does not register Java applications as system-default handlers for document types.

Answer (score 0):

I read about some problems by using *just* the **JavaApplicationStub**. Did you try to build an `.app` with Apple's [Jar Bundler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/About/About.html)? You should be able to [Registering the File Types Your App Supports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html).